# メソッドを経由してデリゲートを設定する方法

Tags: swift, delegate

VIewControllerにTestViewControllerのデリゲート(myDelegate)を設定する際に、
VIewDataのgetViewControllerメソッドを仲介する形式で実現させたいのですが
下記ソースの通り、ViewControllerの `topController.myDelegate = self` でビルドエラーとなります。

デリゲートの使い方が間違っているのでしょうか？そもそもメソッド(getViewController)で
デリゲートを渡す方法はできないのでしょうか？

**VIewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,myDelegate{
//ビューデータ読み込み
    var viewdata = ViewData()
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()   
        var controllers:[UIViewController]=[]
        let topController = viewdata.getViewController("TEST")
        topController.myDelegate = self // ←ここでビルドエラー【Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'newsDelegate’】
        controllers.append(topController)   
        ~~~~~~
     }
    func myTest() {
            ~~~~~~
    }
}
```

**VIewData.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewData{

  func getViewController(_ text:String)->UIViewController{
    switch text{
      case “TEST”:
        let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:nil)
        let TestView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Test") as! TestViewController
        return TestView

      default:
    }

  }

}
```

**TestViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class TestViewController:UITableViewController{
    var myDelegate:myDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        ~~~
    }
    ~~~
    func A(){
        myDelegate?.myTest()　// ここの実行結果をViewControllerで受けたい
    }
}
```

**myDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
protocol myDelegate{
  func myTest()
}
```

Comment: ご提示いただいたサンプルコードには、ケアレスミスがあります。ViewData.swiftの中、`func getViewController(_ text:String)->UIViewController`の宣言で、返り値の型`UIViewController`は、`TestViewController`でなければいけません。このミスを修正して、質問を編集し直していただくと、ご希望に沿った回答を得られるのではないかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。TestViewControllerに変更したところ、topController.myDelegate = self は問題なく動作しました。しかし、getViewControllerのcase文でTestViewController以外の返り値が使えなくなるため、悩んでいます。TestViewController以外の型をcase文毎に返すのは難しいのでしょうか。

Comment: @Y S 私は、回答欄でなく、コメント欄に書きました。ですから、それは回答ではありませんから、あたかも回答であるようなReplyをされても、こちらは困るだけです。私のコメントの主旨は「質問者は質問文を書き直してください。」というところにあります。そこを適切に読み取るかどうか（読み取れるかどうか）が、実は問題解決のいちばんの近道であることに気づいてください。例えばXcodeの出したエラ〜メッセージ「Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'newsDelegate’」をそのままの意味で受け取って、理解しようと努力すれば、自力解決したかもしれませんし、少なくとも、今よりは適切な質問を書くことができたでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

コメントに書かれているように、

`topController.myDelegate = self`

と言う文がコンパイルエラーにならないようにするためには、Swiftコンパイラーに`topController`のデータ型が`TestViewController`であるとわからせておかないといけません。

あなたの今のコードでは、`ViewData.getViewController(_:)`の戻り値は`UIViewController`とはっきり宣言しているのですから、Swiftは`topController`の型を`UIViewController`と認識します。

従って、前の行の`topController`の宣言をこんな風に変えてやる必要があるでしょう。

```
        let topController = viewdata.getViewController("TEST") as! TestViewController
```

Swiftの静的型付けのシステム(コンパイル時に型が決まる)において「TestViewController以外の型をcase文毎に返す」のは、「難しい」のではなく、**不可能** です。

従って、`getViewController(_:)`の中で、`TestView`(別の話になりますが、ローカル変数は小文字スタートにすべきです)の宣言につけている`as! TestViewController`には、あまり意味はありません。

---

正直言って、view controllerをインスタンス化すると言う処理はアプリの中でそう何回も呼ばれる訳でもないため、(現在提示されているコードだけでは)`getViewController(_:)`なんてメソッドを別に定義することのメリットが何も感じられない状態になっています。

なぜswitch文で制御される`getViewController(_:)`のようなメソッドを作ろうと思われたのでしょうか? そこら辺をご提示いただければ、また違う解決方法があるかもしれません。